# Доступ к файлу в корневой директории из поддиректории

Tags: python

Всем привет. У меня есть файл настроек `setting.ini`, который находится в главной директории проекта.

`setting.ini` я читаю в файлу func.py `config.read('setting.ini')`, и все другие файлы, которые импортировали файл func.py, имеют доступ к этому файлу.

Но, когда я обращаюсь к файлу func из другой директории, `routes`, то мне выдает ошибка, KeyError: 'Setting', и мне приходится менять в func на `config.read('../setting.ini')`. Но если сделать так, то скриптам из главной директории не видно этот файл.

Comment: В каждом файле Python определяет переменную `__file__`, которая содержит полный путь к этому файлу. Поэтому вам нужно в `func.py` взять путь из `__file__`, вычленить из него директорию, и прикрепить к этой директории `settings.ini` -- так вы получите полный путь к файлу настроек, который не зависит от того, где вызывается скрипт.

Answer (score 0):

Я делаю так:

```
import os
# Actualised a directory with a script.
abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
os.chdir(dname)
```

Comment: Это не ответ на вопрос. От смены рабочего каталога на корневой у автора вопроса может посыпаться что-нибудь в другом месте.

Comment: Если автор вопроса определил, что у него есть главная директория со скриптами, мой ответ имеет место как вариант решения.